# Manipulating block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there an easy way (maybe a similarity or congruence transform) to turn the matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\ B^T & D
\end{pmatrix}
$$

into the matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & -B \\ -B^T & D
\end{pmatrix}
$$

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\pmatrix{-I & 0 \\ 0 & I}\pmatrix{A & B \\ B^T & D}\pmatrix{-I & 0 \\ 0 & I}=\pmatrix{A & -B \\ -B^T & D}
$$
Since 
$$
\pmatrix{-I & 0 \\ 0 & I}\pmatrix{-I & 0 \\ 0 & I}=I_{2n}
$$
It is a similar transformation.